# VBScript 'Alert' rather than popup

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to the world of VBScript, and I have made a program, that is for a short film about teh new game Watch Dogs.
I have currently got this, as I wanted it to be timed, but I would prefer it if it had no buttons, and it made a noise like the Warning ones (The ones with the red x on the left)
here is my current code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Wshell, BtnCode

Set Wshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("Tracking IP", 1, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("IP Rooted", 2, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("Device Identified as: Smartphone", 2, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("Hacker Identified as: Aide...", 1, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("The Mainframe is under an attack", 2, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.Popup ("Blackout Activated by remote host", 2, "CitiOS Firewall")

BtnCode= Wshell.popup ("Emergency Lockdown In Place", 2, "CitiOS Remote Firewall")
```

Please could I have an example with the answer please :D

Answer (score 1):

```
intButton = object.Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])
```

You can customize the icon and buttons, but no way to hide all buttons. 
Check the values for the last parameter in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).